# Calling text from XML to the manually created object in Activity's method in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create a submit and clear button by a for loop in the onCreate() method by using programming instead of XML layout, and I have defined the label text of the button from the string.xml and assigned it. However, the application has been stopped when I run it.

I have tried to hide the button label setting and it can be work as useal(2 button displayed on the apps without error), thus I am wondering if it is not possible to call string label directly from XML?? or I missed something to do so. Pls give me some comment.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setOrientation(TableLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(tableLayout);

    Button[] buttons = new Button[2];

    //button label
    buttons[0].setText(R.string.label_calc);
    buttons[1].setText(R.string.label_clear);

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new Button(this);
        tableLayout.addView(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the label setting in string.xml:

```
<!-- button label-->
<string name="label_calc">Calc</string>
<string name="label_clear">Clear</string>
```

Not sure why that error happen when I used the resource string.
I have tried the suggestion by Joao below, but virtual device still get into error message "unfortunately, the application has been stopped.

Error message from logcat as below:

04-26 12:20:27.923      992-992/com.skcalc.stockcalculator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skcalc.stockcalculator/com.skcalc.stockcalculator.InfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

I finally fixed it, pls consider it closed.
It is the problem that the label settled before object created.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
buttons[0].setText(getResources().getString(R.string.label_calc));
buttons[1].setText(getResources().getString(R.string.label_clear));
```

to use the strings you defined in the resources.

Comment: Have tried for your suggestion as above, but still in the error. I have posted the error message above for ref.

Comment: By the way, I have tried my declaration and your suggestion, and find that both way are worked. May I know what difference in between our declaration?